# How to create an array assigning new key in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, array-merge

I want to create a new array of size 12 from the following array:

```
$array = [2=>9, 3=>10, 6=>7, 10=>7];
```

I want the following output:

```
$array = [1=>0, 2=>9, 3=>10, 4=>0, 5=>0, 6=>7, 7=>0, 8=>0, 9=>0, 10=>7, 11=>0, 12=>0];
```

Or simply,

```
$array = [0, 9, 10, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0];
```

From 1 to 12, if key does not exists, then set value to 0.

Comment: Is there a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Oneliner](https://3v4l.org/o3CTD):

```
$array = [2=>9, 3=>10, 6=>7, 10=>7];
print_r(array_replace(array_fill(1, 12, 0), $array));
```